# Dynamically binding to ViewModel commands on Window's MenuItem

Tags: wpf, mvvm, command, datatemplate, menuitem

Working on a WPF application using the MVVM structure.

My Window displays a menu and the current ViewModel. On one of the Menu's MenuItems, I want to list some Commands found in the current ViewModel. The commands listed in the Menu will change depending on the ViewModel.

I got this to work just fine, but the style is messed up - the Command MenuItems are inside another menu box or something. I'll attach a screenshot.

I wrapped the ViewModel's ICommand objects (RelayCommands, in this instance) in CommandViewModel, which expose the Command and the Display string I want on the menu. These CommandViewModels are in a list: `CurrentWorkspace.AdditionalOptionsCommands`.

Here is the XAML for the Menu. Like I said, it works, it shows the right items and the commands are executed. The display is just incorrect - can anybody tell me why and how to fix it? See the screenshot.

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="_Additional Options..." ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentWorkspace.AdditionalOptionsCommands}">
        <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CommandViewModel}">
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=DisplayText}" Command="{Binding Path=Command}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="_Testing">
        <MenuItem Header="This looks right" />
        <MenuItem Header="This looks right" />
    </MenuItem>   
</Menu>
```

Current Appearance:

[image: Current Appearance]

Desired Appearance:

[image: Desired Appearance]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because when you specify menu items via `ItemsSource` each item gets automatically wrapped into a `MenuItem` object. This way the content defined in the `DataTemplate` (`MenuItem` element) gets wrapped into one more `MenuItem`.

What you need to do instead of defining a `DataTemplate` is to define a style for the `MenuItem` where you setup bindings to the view model's properties and use this style as `ItemContainerStyle` on the parent `MenuItem`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CommandMenuItemStyle"
           TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
         <Setter Property="Header"
                 Value="{Binding Path=DisplayText}"/> 
         <Setter Property="Command"
                 Value="{Binding Path=Command}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
...
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="_Additional Options..." 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentWorkspace.AdditionalOptionsCommands}" 
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CommandMenuItemStyle}"/>
    <MenuItem Header="_Testing">
        <MenuItem Header="This looks right" />
        <MenuItem Header="This looks right" />
    </MenuItem>   
</Menu>
```

See http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/03/25/itemscontrol-i-is-for-item-container/ for an in-depth explanation on how item containers work with `ItemsControl` controls.